# Selecionar colunas específicas de um repositório no Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, framework, doctrine-2

Primeiramente, sabemos que dependendo da quantidade de colunas de uma consulta, poderá aumentar o tempo de resposta.

No Doctrine chamo o repositório a seguir, que tem um relacionamento e que traz todas as colunas de ambas as entidades.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->alunos = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll();
}
```

Mas pensando na afirmação que dei anteriormente, o retorno deste repositório fica mais demorado do que se fosse uma entidade sem relacionamento?

E outra dúvida?

Posso selecionar as colunas que eu quero que retorne deste repositório? Por exemplo, o repositório acima retorna:

```
id (entidade aluno)
nome (entidade aluno)
id_turma (entidade turma)
```

Porém gostaria que retornasse apenas o nome do aluno.Tipo assim:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->alunos = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll("nome");
    // ou assim pra pegar mais de um campo
    $this->alunos2 = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll("nome, dtNascimento");
}
```

Sei que não funciona assim, foi só pra exemplificar.

Answer (score 1):

Começando pela segunda pergunta, tens a possibilidade de  usar query builders

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM CmsUser u');
$ids = $query->getResult(); // array of CmsUser ids
```

vê aqui: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Quanto à primeira questão:
Em relação a isso penso que a performance pode variar. Se não estou enganado, o Doctrine trata tudo como objectos e ao carregares uma determinada entidade todas as suas dependencias são carregadas.

O Doctrine deixa sim a aplicação mais lenta pelo uso de recursos. Terás de ver o que é mais viáel para ti. Usa ferramentas de profile para medires os recursos usados. penso que em ZendF e Symfony tens componentes que medem isso.

Comment: Opa, +Rudi Rocha, obrigado pela resposta. Então, pra confirmar, não tem como selecionar esses campos pelo repositório não né? Tipo `$this->alunos = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll("nome");` iai traria só o campo nome. PS: sei q não funciona assim, foi só pra exemplificar.

Comment: @LeoFelipe O método findAll() não aceita nome de columnas como argumentos. Penso que o melhor será consultares a documentação em: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é fazer com que você retorne um repositório customizado para uma *model* específica, ao invés de retornar o `EntityReposity` padrão do Doctrine.

Nesse repositório customizado, que herda a classe `EntityRepository`, você sobrescreve as funções de modo que elas retornem apenas as colunas que você quiser.

Classe `MyDomain\Model\Aluno`:

```
<?php

namespace MyDomain\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="MyDomain\Model\AlunoRepository")
 */
class Aluno
{
}
```

Classe `MyDomain\Model\AlunoRepository`:

```
<?php

namespace MyDomain\Model;

class AlunoRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->_em
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT a.coluna1, a.coluna2, a.coluna3
                FROM MyDomain\Model\Aluno a')
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```